# PrimeFaces.ab function

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Cant seem to find documentation for PrimeFaces.ab function

```
PrimeFaces.ab({source:'signupForm:signupButton'});
return false;
```

Can anybody help me with what the code above is meant to do? It has been written against the `onclick` of a submit button.

Answer (score 16):

The [PrimeFaces.ab](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#142) function is a shortcut function for [PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#1091).

```
    //ajax shortcut
    ab: function(cfg, ext) {
        return PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest(cfg, ext);
    }
```

The `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest` can be asynchronous or synchronous.
The [AjaxRequest](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#1091) uses the [AjaxUtils](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#731), which handles all send, process, response, and update.

```
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest = function(cfg, ext) {
    cfg.ext = ext;

    if(cfg.async) {
        return PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.send(cfg);
    }
    else {
        return PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.offer(cfg);
    }
}
```

Passing a cfg (configuration) object to the [PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.send(cfg)](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/tags/4_0/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#817), this cfg object has:

- **cfg.global**: a boolean value used to trigger [p:ajaxStatus](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatus.jsf) if it's a true.
- **cfg.onstart**: to be called when the request is to be send.
- **cfg.async**: a boolean value, where if this call is asynchronous or not.
- **cfg.source**: can be a client id or an element defined by this keyword
- **cfg.formId**: if an explicit form is defined, or it would look into a parent source
- **cfg.resetValues**
- **cfg.ignoreAutoUpdate**
- **cfg.fragmentId**: used for the process of the components
- **cfg.fragmentUpdate**
- **cfg.event**: behaviour event, like click or change
- **cfg.params**: request params
- **cfg.partialSubmit**: if partial submit is enabled, there are components to process partially
- **cfg.onerror**: to be called when the request had an error status.
- **cfg.onsuccess**: to be called when the request had a success status.
- **cfg.oncomplete**: to be called when the request is completed.

Note: I came up with this explanation based on my understanding of the source code.

Also you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207246/primefaces-ab-method), might be helpful.